# Reading text file into C++

Tags: c++, input, io

> I was writing a program which could read inputs directly from a text
>   file into a C++ file. However, the contents of the file come in
>   different formats, for example time. The input file looks like this:

```
Time(1) Price(1)
8:56:18 1250.00
9:00:25 1250.25
9:21:36 1250.50
9:23:32 1249.75

Time(2)
8:55:28
9:02:14
9:20:23
9:21:37
Price(2)
1680.50
1681.00
1680.50
1681.50
```

> My program to read the file is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    string file;
    cout << "Enter a file name to read input: ";
    cin >> file;

    ifstream file_name(file.c_str());

    while(!file_name.eof())
    {
        double input;
        file_name >> input;
        cout << input << endl;
    }
}
```

> But when I executed the program, I get stuck in an infinite loop and
>   all I see are 0s written on the screen. Is this being caused due the
>   formatting of the time?

Comment: Yes, doubles can't hold colons. Also, don't use `while(!eof())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `file_name >> input` is type safe therefore file_name byte offset pointer never increments for inputs like `Time(1)` or `8:56:18`. You may use `string input;` instead of `double input;` to retrieve the values, then later you may check their types by using following standard c library.

```
#include <cstdlib>
.
.
.
atof()
atoi()
.
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) is the documentation.

Comment: How would I be able to convert time to some data type in C++

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time.html

This can be helpful.

Comment: You could use a `struct`ure containing fields like `hours, minutes,` and `seconds`; just a thought though.

Comment: If you really put some effort into the time structure or class, you could overide some operators so that the time structure reads its fields from a file using "hh::mm::ss" format.  Just thinking out loud again.